# how to plot a graph from a matrix and use colume number as x?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I got a 100X100 matrix (let it be M)

I would like to plot a graph with x ranging from 1 to 100 which represents column 1 to column 100 in M.
For each value of x, 100 cooresponding datapoints from each column of M is plotted to the graph.
How should I do that?

I don't know how to formulate the quesiton, sorry for my poor expression.

Comment: Please clarify the question. You can try giving an example of the wanted output.

Comment: Maybe `matplot(seq_len(ncol(M)), M, pch = 19, col = 1)`.

Comment: The matplot's argument takes the row instead of column. So I transpose the matrix using t() and using Rui's code. That's work thx!!

Comment: please share an example of your data using `dput`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this would be an example of 10x10 matrix plotted. for 100x100, change M_size=100 and pivot_longer(V1:V100...)

```
M_size = 10
M <- matrix(rnorm(M_size^2,2,0.5),ncol=M_size)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
M %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(V1:V10,names_to = "col",values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x=col,y=val))+
  geom_point()
```

Comment: That's a bit more complexier but still work. Thank you too!